# Pushing items into an array based on position, clarification

Tags: arrays, angularjs, list, push

So the code is as follows,

```
var getData = function (){
$http.get('data/location')
.success(function(newDataObj){
$scope.newList = [];

var list = JSON.parse(newDataObj);

for(var x in list){
$scope.newList.push(list[x])
}
```

I understand the principle of almost all of this, the only part I would appreciated clarification on is the list[x], what exactly is the [x] referring to?

From what I understand the for loop will iterate through the list array and push the first object it encounters throughout array into the newList, so is the [x] in reference to the current position in the array?

Sorry if this seems like a rookie question but I'd rather have a complete understanding of it than guessing at it's functionality.

Kind regards,

Sam

Comment: `for(var x in list)` is used for `for(var key in object)`, but the key in the array are the index values (0,1,2,3,...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`x`** is the index of the array named list.

```
for(var x in list){
   $scope.newList.push(list[x])
}
```

where you are accessing the element with the specific index and pushing to the newList scope variable.